# OnClick en Fragment no cambia mi TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

```
public class MainMenu extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);

        Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnme1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View vi) {
        int id = vi.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.btnme1:
                TextView ncant1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtcant1);
                ncant1.setText("85");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Deseo colocar el numero 85 en un textview [R.id.txtcant1] al presionar el boton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código esta errado en el método `OnClick`, ya que estás buscando la referencia del TextView con una vista errónea (`vi`) que es la referencia del `Button`.

Si vas a utilizar un widget fuera del contexto local, te recomiendo declararlo global como en este caso:

```
public class MainMenu extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

        private TextView ncant1;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);
            ncant1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtcant1);
            Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnme1);
            b.setOnClickListener(this);
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View vi) {
            int id = vi.getId();
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.btnme1:
                    ncant1.setText("85");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```